# ところ pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent

NHK seems to suggest there are two pitch patterns for ところ but they appear to come with different meanings. The word referring to physical locations seems to be 尾高 ところ＼, e.g.
いろんなところで{LHHHHHHL}

The figurative sense seems to be read 平板. そういうところもある{LHHHHHHHHL}. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

No, 新NHK has the following examples for 平板,

> ところにより雨
>
> ところ変われば

I think it is generally rarer, and the one in question is そういうところ＼もあ＼る for both figurative ('he is inclined for that') and non-figurative usage ('there are such places').

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between the 平板 word and 尾高 word? Why is ところ 平板 in ところにより雨 and ところ変われば?

Comment: @EddieKal I guess there is not much *why* like for most pronunciations, but both being set-phrase may be a factor. ところどころ can be ところどころ or ところ＼どころ＼. Also I think when ところ is followed by a particle, it is mostly 尾高.

Comment: Another set-phrase: ところせまし. I think both are possible but 平板 is more normal.

Comment: It’s 平板 because it is not preceded by a modifier. ところ is one of several words that changes to 尾高 when it is preceded by something that modifies it. Certain set phrases are also 尾高.

Answer (score 3):

There are a set of nouns that are either heiban or odaka depending on whether they are modified in front (i.e.: 〜のところ＼、〜のひと＼、〜のうえ＼).

ところ is odaka when modified and heiban when it's not. However in certain phrases it's still odaka like: ところ＼が and ところ＼で.

If you look at Shinmeikai it tells you more directly:

> 前に修飾句がない時は０、前に修飾句がある時は３

0 when there is not modifier in front, 3 if there is a modifier in front